# How to form select distinct(parameter) query in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, distinct-values

example :

```
select distinct(city) from employee_details where name="JOHN";
```

How to form select distinct(parameter) query in Apache Solr ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use facets to produce distinct values

```
q=name:JOHN&facet=true&facet.field=city&rows=0
```

try to run above query

Comment: For a normal sql query : select city from employee_details where name="JOHN"; we define parameters like q=name:JOHN  & fl=city. So can you please elaborate your answer for distinct query; I'm not able to understand it

Comment: @Deepti add the query for the same.Please check

Comment: its not executing

Comment: The query should work from your example - what error do you get?

Comment: something like this.....{
  "error": {
    "msg": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space",
    "trace": "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:673)\n\tat 
    "code": 500
  }
}

Comment: I think OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error is not related to the SOLR query itself, may be you are trying to fetch facets from a big data SOLR. You can limit the count of facets using facet.mincount=1 to remove factes that have not data from being fetched